# How can I add line numbers to Vim?

Tags: line-numbers

I'd like to see line numbers, starting with `1` at the top, on the left side of Vim. Ideally it would look like this:

```
1 | foo = Foo.new
2 | bar = Bar.new
3 | baz = foo.baz(bar)
...
10| test = AwesomeSauce.test
```

How can I do this in Vim?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have two options:
`set number` for regular line numbers

And also
`set relativenumber` which will show relative line numbers. i.e. current line is always 0. This is useful for moving up/down N number of lines using `5j` for example.

What is cool is that you can combine them. I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
set number                     " Show current line number
set relativenumber             " Show relative line numbers
```

This will make it use relative numbers for all lines except the current line, which will show you the actual number.

Comment: Now I tried this, and it's a schyzo! I mean, confusing. :D

Comment: You can also toggle the commands by appending a "!" to them. E.g. `set number!` will turn on line numbering if it's off, and turn it on if it's off.
`set relativenumber` can be shortened as `set rnu`.

Comment: here is a shortcut: `:se nu` to turn on line numbers and `:se nu!` to toggle - on if it is off, off if it is on

Answer (score 23):

You can use the command:

```
:set number
```

to turn on line numbering.  To turn it off again you can use:

```
:set nonumber
```

If you want vim to always default to showing line numbers you can add the command to your `vimrc` file.

`nu` and `nonu` can be used as aliases for `number` and `nonumber` respectively.

Comment: Here's a small abbreviation:
:set nu " to enable
:set nonu " to disable

Comment: another shortcut: `:se nu` to turn on line numbers and `:se nu!` to toggle - on if it is off, off if it is on