# How can I show relative line numbers?

Tags: line-numbers

A lot of vim commands can take a number referring to the number of lines that the command will act on.

Is it possible to show the line numbers relative to the current line? Something like the following:

```
3: some text here
2: more text
1: This is the line above where the cursor is
0: The cursor is on this line
1: This is the line after the cursor
2: More text here
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I just replied to a similar question here: [How can I add line numbers to Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-add-line-numbers-to-vim)

Beginning with version 7.3, you can use the following:

```
set relativenumber
```

I actually use both `relativenumber` and `number` in my vimrc which will use relative numbers for all lines except the current line.

```
set number                     " Show current line number
set relativenumber             " Show relative line numbers
```

Comment: Not sure exactly but the first changelog its mentioned in is 7.3.
ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/README

Comment: @aturegano your edits were quite substantial, and I felt they would be better as a new answer than as a part of this one. Others may disagree (your edit is still pending review), but please consider it!

Comment: you might enjoy the hybrid mode `:set nu rnu`

Comment: @user1068352  's comment could also be `:set number relativenumber`. It's useful those shorter versions of commands, but I like the full version to keep them in mind easier.

Answer (score 25):

You can toggle relative numbering on and off using:

```
:set rnu    " toggle relative numbering on
:set rnu!   " toggle relative numbering off
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use a hotkey for toggling relative line number, here is a snippet in my vimrc:

```
" Toggle relative line number
nmap <C-L><C-L> :set invrelativenumber<CR>
```

In this case, I use ctrl-L twice to toggle it.

Answer (score 5):

```
function! NumberToggle()
  if(&relativenumber == 1)
    set norelativenumber
  else
    set relativenumber
  endif
endfunc

nnoremap <leader>nt :call NumberToggle()<cr>
```

Comment: Does the norelativenumber just turn off numbering altogether or does it switch to conventional numbering?

Comment: `set number` is the setting that controls the presences of numbers so it will only switch between rel and non-rel

Comment: The `numbers.vim` plugin also adds some more advanced relative number functionality, e.g. having the line your cursor occupies printing the non-relative number, and switching to non-relative numbering throughout the whole file when the vim window loses focus.

Comment: @shawndumas so is there a precedence of which numbers are shown? If for instance I had set number in my vimrc and set relativenumber / norelativenumber was called could it toggle between relative and standard numbering?

Comment: that is most correct

Comment: simply `set rnu!` toggles relative and absolute numbers too

Comment: Is there any benefit to using solution this over the accepted/other answers?